# Create new list out of List<CustomObject> with respect to a value

Tags: java, list, filter

I have a List with certain entries. Each entry has a SourceTitle. Multiple entries can have the same SourceTitle. I want to create a new list which contains entries with the same SourceTitle.

How can I filter my list?

Comment: words better described by codes

Comment: What do you expect if your `List` contains many groups sharing the same `SourceTitle`?

Comment: Down-vote from me - doesn't look like you've attempted anything. Also - what exactly is a `SourceTitle` - what type?

Answer (score 0):

This small example (its just example code) iterates over each entry in your `List` and creates as many `lists` with the same `SourceTitle` as found in your `List`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<MyEntry> entries = Arrays.asList(newEntry("A"), newEntry("B"), newEntry("B"), newEntry("A"));
    Map<String, List<MyEntry>> lists = new HashMap<>();
    for (MyEntry entry : entries) {
        List<MyEntry> list = lists.get(entry.sourceTitle);
        if (list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<>();
            lists.put(entry.sourceTitle, list);
            list.add(entry);
        }
    }
}

class MyEntry {

    String sourceTitle;
    public static MyEntry newEntry(String sourceTitle) {
        MyEntry entry = new MyEntry();
        entry.sourceTitle = sourceTitle;
        return entry;
    }
}
```

- `lists.keySet()` contains all different `SourceTitles` found.
- `lists.values()` contains all list of entries sharing the same `SourceTitle`.